# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [SessionFactory] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [SessionFactory]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying use Hibernate for Db access in my Spring app. But now, I am getting the follow error:

```
Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [SessionFactory] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [SessionFactory].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.ligadesportiva.data.UsuarioHome.getSessionFactory(UsuarioHome.java:28)
    at org.ligadesportiva.data.UsuarioHome.<init>(UsuarioHome.java:23)
    at org.ligadesportiva.controller.controller.login(controller.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

This is my class DAO (UsuarioHome.java):

```
package org.ligadesportiva.data;

// Generated 15/03/2014 09:34:19 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.LockMode;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Example;
import org.ligadesportiva.core.Usuario;

/**
 * Home object for domain model class Usuario.
 * @see org.ligadesportiva.core.Usuario
 * @author Hibernate Tools
 */
public class UsuarioHome {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UsuarioHome.class);

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();

    protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext()
                    .lookup("SessionFactory");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
        }
    }

    public void persist(Usuario transientInstance) {
        log.debug("persisting Usuario instance");
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
            log.debug("persist successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void attachDirty(Usuario instance) {
        log.debug("attaching dirty Usuario instance");
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
            log.debug("attach successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("attach failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void attachClean(Usuario instance) {
        log.debug("attaching clean Usuario instance");
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().lock(instance, LockMode.NONE);
            log.debug("attach successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("attach failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void delete(Usuario persistentInstance) {
        log.debug("deleting Usuario instance");
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(persistentInstance);
            log.debug("delete successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("delete failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public Usuario merge(Usuario detachedInstance) {
        log.debug("merging Usuario instance");
        try {
            Usuario result = (Usuario) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .merge(detachedInstance);
            log.debug("merge successful");
            return result;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("merge failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public Usuario findById(int id) {
        log.debug("getting Usuario instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            Usuario instance = (Usuario) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .get("org.ligadesportiva.data.Usuario", id);
            if (instance == null) {
                log.debug("get successful, no instance found");
            } else {
                log.debug("get successful, instance found");
            }
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public List findByExample(Usuario instance) {
        log.debug("finding Usuario instance by example");
        try {
            List results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria("org.ligadesportiva.data.Usuario")
                    .add(Example.create(instance)).list();
            log.debug("find by example successful, result size: "
                    + results.size());
            return results;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("find by example failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```

This method are being called from my controller, this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        Usuario temp = new Usuario(username, convertByteToHex(digest));
        UsuarioHome tempHome = new UsuarioHome();
        List<Usuario> lista = tempHome.findByExample(temp);
        if(lista.size() == 0) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("usuario_login");
            mav.addObject("message", "N&atilde;o foi possivel efetuar o login");
            return mav;
        }
        else {
            this.sessao = new Sessao();
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("usuario_start");
            mav.addObject("usuario", temp);
            return mav;
        }
    }
```

Someone can identify what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**
Following the sugestion from CodeBlender, I add to my project this class (in package org.ligadesportiva.resources):

```
package org.ligadesportiva.resources;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:database.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.ligadesportiva.data" })
public class HibernateConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.ligadesportiva.core" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource restDataSource() {
      BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
      dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
      dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
      dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
      HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

      return txManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   Properties hibernateProperties() {
      return new Properties() {
         {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
         }
      };
   }
}
```

and add this line to my class UsuarioHome (DAO class):

```
private HibernateConfig hibernateConfig = new HibernateConfig();

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) hibernateConfig.sessionFactory();
```

I don't know if what I do it's right, but the error message change to this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is caused by `(SessionFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("SessionFactory")`. Since you're using spring framework, I would recommend you to go with the IoC approach instead of using InitialContext. =)

To use SessionFactory, you need to initialise this class with several properties, such as the dataSource, hibernateProperties, entities, etc.. And it is usually done either with the XML or Annotation-Driven approach. You would configure SessionFactory and let it live in your IoC container, then inject it into your UsuarioHome class.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/hibernate-3-with-spring.html

The above link show both methods (XML and Annotation). Trying following it and set up beans. =D

UPDATE: This mkyong's tutorial contains step-by-step tutorial and pretty clear as well! http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/

Comment: I did a change in my project, trying follow the orientation of the first link you indicate me, and in fact, I am receiving a new error message. Can you give a look in my update and see what I am make wrong now? I would be very thankful with any help.

Comment: Can you show me your spring-servlet.xml? And you should just do @Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory in your UsuarioHome class.

Comment: this is my spring(?)-servlet.xml (do you mean ligadesportiva-servlet.xml, right? it's the servlet-name in the web.xml file) -> http://i.imgur.com/1hldORK.png. I put the @Autowired in my UsuarioHome class too.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html says that you need to add context:annotation-config tag to your *servlet.xml. give it a try?

Comment: It work for stop the NullPointerException above, but now I have this error: http://imgur.com/6prFTbh

Comment: It says that the exceptionTranslation() method is missing the cacheProvider bean. If you do not need exceptionTranslation method, u can remove it. If you need it, u have to configure cacheProvider bean.